# i am trying to use constructor in controller but failed !Why my constructor not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-10

```
public function __construct()
{
     if (Auth::check()){
        if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin'){
            return to_route('admin.dashboard');
        } elseif(Auth::user()->user_type == 'operator'){
            return to_route('operator.dashboard');
        }
     }
}
```

I am checking user authentication.

Answer (score 3):

After user login you are redirecting the users to a route and that route points to a function, so basically you can implement this with a middleware or a simple function of redirect instead of constructor which is to initialize an object's properties.

```
 public function redirect()
    {
        $role = Auth::user()->role;
        return match ($role) {
            'Admin' => redirect('/admin/dashboard'),
            'Operator' => redirect('/operator'),
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible by design. If you need it you can create middleware in constructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if (Auth::check()){
           if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin'){
              return to_route('admin.dashboard');
           } elseif(Auth::user()->user_type == 'operator'){
              return to_route('operator.dashboard');
           }
         }
 
         return $next($request);
    });
}
```

but you can also create normal middleware and use it for controller.

See this [Laravel change](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) to get more explanation

Comment: def would need a middleware if you want to access the session in the constructor ... the only thing is they are trying to return a string from a middleware, which is a big no no ... nice to see you active my friend

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller method, don't do it in the constructor. Constructors in Laravel controllers do not typically return values.

```
public function someMethod()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->user_type === 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        } elseif (Auth::user()->user_type === 'operator') {
            return redirect()->route('operator.dashboard');
        }
    }

    //...
}
```